# jupyter notebook memory leak?

Tags: memory, jupyter-notebook

I start a new session of jupyter notebook, without loading anything. just a fresh session.

```
svmem(total=34093076480, available=22954254336, percent=32.7, used=11138822144, free=22954254336)
```

using psutil.virtual_memory() I caan see that even a fresh session is using 11G of memory.

any guidance how to cure this memory leak from Jupytper notebook please?

thanks.